# How to create function variables with parameter in extensions?

Tags: swift, swift-extensions

When working with Swift - Extensions

As you know, we can create variables for function. i want to create a variable which can hold reference to a function which has parameters.

i have managed to create variable for a function which didn't have any parameters defined for

My code is as follows :-

```
extension UIAlertController {


    var cancelBlock : ()->Void  { return {} }

    var nameBlock : (nameArg:String?)->Void  { }

}
```

I am getting the following error with "nameBlock"

```
Computed property must have accessors specified
```

How should i specify return value ?

Comment: Make a method instead

Comment: @LeoDabus : sorry , couldn't get you.. Please explain.

Comment: Properties you can only define the return type

Comment: You need to create a method `func nameBlock(parameter: Type) -> TypeToReturn { ... }`

Comment: @LeoDabus I want to use this function variable as block / closure . (i.e replace this with another block of code in a function defined in the extension ). how will i be able to do that

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "replace this with another block"? Extensions don't allow stored properties, anyway, so you'll have to store it somewhere yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use
**var nameBlock : (nameArg:String?)->Void?  { return nil }**

Comment: this is a computed property that should return an optional method but instead of it it always returns nil. I am still trying to understand what would be the use of it